# calculated field in SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access

I need to Add a field named "calc" that is calculated as

```
if D.type_id = 1
then calc = calc + D.price
and if D.type_id = 2
then calc = clac - D.price
```

what exactly should I add to the next SQL code to do that.

```
SELECT T.type_name, D.*, I.name_inout
  FROM ((Type T
  INNER JOIN Daily D ON (T.type_id=D.type_id))
  INNER JOIN Incom I ON (I.id_inout=D.id_inout))
  WHERE D.today = DATE()
  Order by daily_id
```

I really don't care about the field .. I just care about the final result of "calc" as I'll pass the final value to a Report.

Comment: So you're looking for a running total, correct?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: Please don't tag with tags that are completely irrelevant, like c++builder in this case. It just adds noise and is annoying.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm reading the question correctly, you need a case statement.

```
SELECT 
    case D.type_id 
        when 1 then calc + D.price
        when 2 then calc - D.price
        else <<whatever your default is>>
    end as CalculatedPrice,
    T.type_name, D.*, I.name_inout
  FROM (
    (
        Type T
        INNER JOIN Daily D ON (T.type_id=D.type_id)
    )
  INNER JOIN Incom I ON (I.id_inout=D.id_inout))
  WHERE D.today = DATE()
  Order by daily_id
```

If you want the SUM of the calculated prices using your formula, then you need a wrapped table as follows:

```
select sum(dtA.CalculatedPrice)
From (
  SELECT 
    case D.type_id 
        when 1 then calc + D.price
        when 2 then calc - D.price
        else <<whatever your default is>>
    end as CalculatedPrice,
    T.type_name, D.*, I.name_inout
  FROM (
    (
        Type T
        INNER JOIN Daily D ON (T.type_id=D.type_id)
    )
  INNER JOIN Incom I ON (I.id_inout=D.id_inout))
  WHERE D.today = DATE()
 ) dtA
```

Comment: actually I was hoping for another answer. As I did write your code before ..  exactly the same way without the "else" statement, but an error appears (unrecognized keyword WHEN). I thought I miss writing it, but now I guess not. I forgot to tell you that I am using MS Access Database and "D.price" is a (Text) which should be converted to (Double) so I can do subtraction and adding calculation

Comment: If you're using Access, then the CASE statement becomes IIF.  Reference this article for details on how to use IIF.  http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/advanced/iif.php